# How to separate images using watershed algorithm in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, data-science

How to separate indiviual images among multiple images after image segmentaion using watershed algorithm in Python
The attached image is consists of 4 images , from which we need to apply image segmentation and separate individual image from those 4 images 
[image]

Comment: I dont think watershed will apply to this case

Comment: Can you please advise , how this can be solved.

Answer (score 6):

We will flood fill it first

```py
import cv2;
import numpy as np;

# Read image
im_in = cv2.imread("2SNAT.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

# Threshold.
# Set values equal to or above 220 to 0.
# Set values below 220 to 255.

th, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_in, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

# Copy the thresholded image.
im_floodfill = im_th.copy()

# Mask used to flood filling.
# Notice the size needs to be 2 pixels than the image.
h, w = im_th.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)

# Floodfill from point (0, 0)
cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0,0), 255);

# Invert floodfilled image
im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)

# Combine the two images to get the foreground.
im_out = im_th | im_floodfill_inv
```

[image: Filled image]

Then find contour and crop out

```py
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_out.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

final_contours = []
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if area > 1000:
        final_contours.append(contour)
```

Crop out step, also drawing rectangle on original image

```py
counter = 0        
for c in final_contours:
    counter = counter + 1
# for c in [final_contours[0]]:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.01 * peri, True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    print(x, y, w, h)
    aspect_ratio = w / float(h)

    if (aspect_ratio >= 0.8 and aspect_ratio <= 4):
        cv2.rectangle(im_in,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.imwrite('splitted_{}.jpg'.format(counter), im_in[y:y+h, x:x+w])
cv2.imwrite('rectangled_split.jpg', im_in)
```

[image: Drawed square]
[image: Result]

Comment: @Ashish im not expert in this field, so my way probably not the best, if you need more explain just comment,

Comment: You nailed it buddy. We are almost near the solution.  Just getting the below error message : ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7d84b7e36ebb> in <module>
----> 1 contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
      2 
      3 final_contours = []
      4 for contour in contours:
      5     area = cv2.contourArea(contour)

TypeError: findContours() missing required argument 'method' (pos 3)

Comment: Thanks Buddy for the quick help and response , Also from the output image of 1st block of code , is it possible to only fetch individual image itself  like four yellow shaded images individually from the first diagram which actually is actually the need ( not with the square boundary )

Comment: the semicolons at line ends are not necessary in Python

Comment: @Ashish the `findContours` line of code you use is lacking the first argument of image input, `im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_out.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`

Also if you want to fetch yellow shaded image, , change this line (crop and writing to file) `cv2.imwrite('splitted_{}.jpg'.format(counter), im_in[y:y+h, x:x+w])` to `cv2.imwrite('splitted_{}.jpg'.format(counter), im_out[y:y+h, x:x+w])`

Comment: Also, @nathancy answer nailed it better than mine,

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using watershed, here's a simple approach using thresholding + morphological operations. The idea is to obtain a binary image then perform morph close to combine each object as a single contour. We then find contours and extract/save each ROI using Numpy slicing.

Here's each individual object highlighted in green

[image]

Individual saved object

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,7))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)

# Find contours and extract ROI
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
num = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(num), ROI)
    num += 1

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks @nathancy . The above logic doesn't work with the image which are not aligned properly. Can you advise how to work with the image https://imgur.com/ngxJcow  so that there are two separate image A and B which i have described in the image. Thanks in advance

Comment: If its not a rectangular shaped object, you have to use bitwise masking. Find contours and draw each contour onto a blank mask in white then bitwise-and with the original input. From here find the bounding box on the mask and extract the ROI